# Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-function, strict, postgresql-performance

I stumbled upon a slump in performance when a simple SQL function is declared `STRICT` while [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455172/939860).

For demonstration, I created two variants of a function ordering two elements of an array in ascending order.

#### Test setup

Table with 10000 random pairs of integer (

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (arr int[]);

INSERT INTO tbl 
SELECT ARRAY[(random() * 1000)::int, (random() * 1000)::int]
FROM   generate_series(1,10000);
```

Function without `STRICT` modifier:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sort_array(int[])
  RETURNS int[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1[1] > $1[2] THEN ARRAY[$1[2], $1[1]] ELSE $1 END;
$func$;
```

Function with `STRICT` modifier (otherwise identical):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sort_array_strict(int[])
  RETURNS int[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1[1] > $1[2] THEN ARRAY[$1[2], $1[1]] ELSE $1 END;
$func$;
```

#### Results

I executed each around 20 times and took the best result from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```sql
SELECT f_sort_array(arr)        FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:  43 ms
SELECT f_sort_array_strict(arr) FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime: 103 ms
```

These are the results from Postgres 9.0.5 on Debian Squeeze. Similar results on 8.4.

In a test with all NULL values both functions perform the same: ~37 ms.

I did some research and found an interesting gotcha. Declaring an SQL function **STRICT disables function-inlining** in most cases. More about that in the [PostgreSQL Online Journal](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/163-STRICT-on-SQL-Function-Breaks-In-lining-Gotcha.html) or in the [pgsql-performance mailing list](https://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2011-11/msg00119.php) or in the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions).

But I am not quite sure how this could be the explanation. Not inlining the function causes a performance slump in this simple scenario? No index, no disc read, no sorting. Maybe an overhead from the repeated function call that is streamlined away by inlining the function?

#### Retests

Same test, same hardware, **Postgres 9.1**. Even bigger differences:

```sql
SELECT f_sort_array(arr)        FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:  27 ms
SELECT f_sort_array_strict(arr) FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime: 107 ms
```

Same test, new hardware, **Postgres 9.6**. The gap is even bigger, yet:

```sql
SELECT f_sort_array(arr)        FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:  10 ms
SELECT f_sort_array_strict(arr) FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:  60 ms
```

Comment: These two functions are not equivalent.
`STRICT` is not a hint but an instruction, "don't call this with null arguments".  This will result in a not null check that you haven't explicitly asked for, hence comment not answer.

I am however surprised that when I tested this on a table with a `NOT NULL` modifier, this still has the same effect.

Comment: @couling: The example function yields identical results with or without STRICT. "Common sense" would tell me that STRICT is faster, if NULL values are involved, but that's not the case. I added a quick test with NULLs to my question.

Comment: Just because null values are not involved does not mean postgres knows that they are not involved.  It may still have to check.

Comment: Good and well researched question, why the downvote!?

Comment: The Pg developer must  read this post  as a **bug report**. BigBig loss of performance destroys any expectation of `STRICT`  users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe an overhead from the repeated function call that is streamlined away by inlining the function?

That's what I'd guess. You've got a very simple expression there. An actual function-call presumably involves stack setup, passing parameters etc.

The test below gives run-times of 5ms for inlined and 50ms for strict.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE SCHEMA f;

SET search_path = f;

CREATE FUNCTION f1(int) RETURNS int AS $$SELECT 1$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION f2(int) RETURNS int AS $$SELECT 1$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT;

\timing on
SELECT sum(f1(i)) FROM generate_series(1,10000) i;
SELECT sum(f2(i)) FROM generate_series(1,10000) i;
\timing off

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Yep, STRICT functions cannot be inlined, and thus can be a lot slower especially for simple expressions. Personally I'm a little surprised Pg doens't inline them effectively as `CASE WHEN input IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE func(input) END` (or some simpler-to-evaluate function-like equivalent) but I'm sure it can't be that simple or they would've done it long ago.

Comment: @CraigRinger: There is one important difference between Richard's function and mine above. `STRICT` *changes* the result of this function when called with `NULL`. So it is remotely understandable that it should perform slower. The lesson we learn here: don't use STRICT for simple functions unless you *need* it. There is definitely potential here for optimization like you say, but it is small and for simple cases only, so we may never see it happen. This should be **documented**. I am pretty sure most people are surprised by the effect.

Comment: This **bug report** was in 2011... And nowadays, (2019!) the bug persist... How to say to PostgreSQL development team that this is a relevant **bug**. No vote system?

Comment: What bug report? An optimisation not being applied in a corner case isn't a bug. A feature request, but not a bug. There is a well documented (but fairly rigorous, naturally) method for offering patches if you are inclined.

Answer (score 1):

It's about function inlining like suspected and confirmed by Richard's test.

**To be clear**, the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) lists this requirement for inlining of a scalar function (like my example):

> - if the function is declared `STRICT`, then the planner must be able to prove that the body expression necessarily returns `NULL` if any parameter is null. At present, this condition is only satisfied if: every parameter is referenced at least once, and all functions, operators and other constructs used in the body are themselves `STRICT`.

The example function obviously does not qualify. Both the `CASE` construct and the `ARRAY` constructor are to blame according to my tests.

Table functions (returning a set of rows) are more picky, yet:

> - the function is not declared `STRICT`

If the function cannot be inlined, repeated execution collects the function overhead repeatedly. The difference in performance got bigger in later Postgres versions.

Retest with **PostgreSQL 13** on a current laptop. Bigger difference, yet:

```sql
SELECT f_sort_array(arr)        FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:   4 ms
SELECT f_sort_array_strict(arr) FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:  32 ms
```

Same test on dbfiddle.com, **PostgreSQL 13**. Bigger difference, yet:

```sql
SELECT f_sort_array(arr)        FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime:   4 ms
SELECT f_sort_tblay_strict(arr) FROM tbl;  -- Total runtime: 137 ms (!)
```

Comprehensive test including tests with half and all NULL values:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b60065e8afc54f096319edf7b92615b)*