# Is it possible to cache variable in PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

**Context**

I'm building a Postgres extension, which adds possibility to ask fuzzy queries with linguistic variables. For example:

```
SELECT age~=('age'|>'adult') FROM people;
```

will return the plausibility of the fact that a person is an adult (adult is defined as a trapezoidal function `30/40~60\65`.

**Problem**

I made a function that allows to return the linguistic name for specified value and linguistic variable:

```
SELECT age, age~>'age' FROM people;
```

returns

```
 age | age~>'age'
-----+--------------
 20  | young adult
 10  | child
 45  | adult
 60  | old
```

Source of this function and operator looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_fuzzy_name(
  input FLOAT8,
  type_name VARCHAR(64)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(64) AS $$
DECLARE
  type_id fuzzy.types.id%TYPE;
  deg FLOAT8;
  result_name VARCHAR(64);
BEGIN
  type_id := get_fuzzy_type(type_name); -- returns type's id based on it's name
  SELECT
      degree(input, fun) AS d, name
    INTO
      deg, result_name
    FROM fuzzy.functions
    WHERE type=type_id
    ORDER BY d DESC LIMIT 1;
  IF deg=0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN result_name;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE OPERATOR ~> (
  PROCEDURE = get_fuzzy_name,
  LEFTARG = FLOAT8,
  RIGHTARG = VARCHAR(64)
);
```

The problem is, that for every row, the function above queries for fuzzy type and functions again and again. So I came up with this, as a base for improvements (fuzzy functions are held in a variable):

```
CREATE TYPE FUZZY_TYPE_FUNCTION AS (
  func  TRAPEZOIDAL_FUNCTION,
  range_name VARCHAR(64)
);
CREATE FUNCTION get_fuzzy_name(
  input FLOAT8,
  type_name VARCHAR(64)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(64) AS $$
DECLARE
  f FUZZY_TYPE_FUNCTION;
  _type_functions FUZZY_TYPE_FUNCTION[] := array(SELECT (fun, name) FROM fuzzy.functions WHERE fuzzy.functions.type=type_name);
  _deg_tmp FLOAT8;
  _deg FLOAT8;
  _result_name VARCHAR(64);
BEGIN
  _deg := 0;
  FOREACH f IN array(_type_functions) LOOP
    _deg_tmp := degree(input, f.func);
    RAISE NOTICE '% && % = %', f, input, _deg_tmp;
    IF _deg<_deg_tmp THEN
      _deg := _deg_tmp;
      _result_name := f.range_name;
      EXIT WHEN _deg=1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF _deg=0 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  RETURN _result_name;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Is there a way to get the value of functions table just once per query and cache it, so it could be reused and drastically speed up the whole query?

**Additional information**

As requested, this are the tables:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fuzzy;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fuzzy.types (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fuzzy.functions (
  type INT                  NOT NULL,
  fun  TRAPEZOIDAL_FUNCTION NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES fuzzy.types (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE (type, name)
);
```

`fuzzy.types` will probably contain a few rows which are id-name pairs, 
`fuzzy.functions` will most likely contain 3-10 rows per each type, which for heavy use cases may be about 500 rows (I guess).

Comment: What does the `fuzzy.functions` table look like? Does it hold a few rows only, and if so, can you show or describe what those rows hold? What about `type_id := get_fuzzy_type(type_name)`, how many different results can this return?

Comment: As the function is declared `immutable` it will only be called once for each pair of input values. The problem is: it shouldn't be declared as `immutable` as it accesses tables in the database. You can only declare it as `stable` and in that case the results for the same input should also be cached.

Comment: Thank you! @eurotrash I've added additional information. I also made a benchmark showing that the first query completes in 24s for ~1M rows and the second one is 2 times slower. I wouldn't mind rewriting the whole mechanism to something else, but for now I wonder if there is possibility to cache just one variable in a function. I know that aggregates can store state, but it's probably not applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be building on a couple of misleading assumptions about function performance.

Try this simplified SQL function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_fuzzy_name(_input FLOAT8, _type_name VARCHAR(64))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(64) AS
$func$
   SELECT f.name
   FROM   fuzzy.functions f
   JOIN   fuzzy.types     t ON t.id = f.type
   WHERE  t.name = _type_name
   AND    degree(_input, f.fun) > 0
   ORDER  BY degree(_input, f.fun) DESC
   LIMIT  1;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

- `LANGUAGE sql`. No variables, assignments, `IF` constructs, ... 1 simple query.
  Complete rewrite, but should be equivalent.
- `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`.
- No nested function call at all. Replaced with a join. Should be cheaper.
- It might be cheaper, yet, to inline the undisclosed `degree()` function as well. *May* even burn down to a much faster "nearest neighbor" query. Not enough info.
- This function can be *inlined* as opposed to your original.
  I removed `STRICT`, which might be in the way. Can't tell, not enough info.

See the [Postgres Wiki about inlining of scalar functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_scalar_functions).
And:

- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier)

Related:

- [PostgreSQL UDF (User Defined Functions) overhead](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220854/3684)

Comment: Thanks! The change to plain SQL function type has improved performance from ~25s to ~20s for the same data set. I'd like to improve it further by rewriting the whole mechanism to C later - I'll post results here when it's ready.