# How to apply a function to each element of a json array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

Given this function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_key(
  i_m JSONB,
  i_key TEXT
) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN i_m -> i_key;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I'd like to write a function `extract_key_array` where:

```sql
SELECT extract_key_array('hello', '[{"hello": {"id": 1}} ,{"hello": {"id": 2}}]')
```

outputs a json array: `'[{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is basically good. A couple of improvments:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_key_array(_key text, _arr jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT jsonb_agg(elem -> _key) FROM jsonb_array_elements(_arr) elem;
$func$;
```

Works with your desired function call:

```sql
SELECT extract_key_array('hello', '[{"hello": {"id": 1}} ,{"hello": {"id": 2}}]')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=99a8ba3aad3937918ec7b8352705a384)*

- A simple SQL function does the job and can be *inlined*.
- Declare the function `STABLE` and `PARALLEL SAFE` (because it *is*!) This allows for various optimizations in query plans.
  (Don't declare it `IMMUTABLE` as the contained `jsonb_agg()` is only `STABLE` for some unknown reason.)
- You answer switched the order of function parameters displayed in the question.

About function inlining:

- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier/65672967#65672967)

Answer (score 0):

This works but maybe there's a faster method.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_key_array(
  i_arr JSONB,
  i_key TEXT
) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN jsonb_agg(extract_key(out,i_key)) FROM jsonb_array_elements(i_arr) AS out;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```