# Postgresql 9.3: Can I cast a column in a UNIQUE constraint?

Tags: postgresql, casting, constraints

Is it possible in Postgresql 9.3 to apply a UNIQUE constraint to a table where one of the columns in the constraint is casted?  I have a TIMESTAMP column that I would like to cast to a DATE and use as part of the UNIQUE constraint.  However, Postgresql is throwing a syntax error.

See full example with [My SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/484be/1)

Comment: Do you need a constraint? I think constraint can't use expression, but a unique *index* can. The following works and serves more or less the same purpos: `create UNIQUE index on student_attendance (fullname, class, cast(record_time as date));`

Comment: This is very similar to [Postgres UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443716/479863) but I'm not sure if it counts as a duplicate. Same solution in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Unique Index did the trick:

create UNIQUE index on student_attendance (fullname, class, cast(record_time as date));

credit goes to ***a_horse_with_no_name***