# Handling concurrent INSERTs for a unique array value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My app receives events from external services, then resolves an external id received in the event to an internal user id, if no internal user exists it should create one.

My `users` table is defined in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, /* internal unique ID */
    external_ids text[], /* array of unique external IDs for this user */
     /* ... irrelevant data fields */
);
```

When a new event is received I have to resolve the internal user `id` for that event to further determine what is the appropriate response.
If no user is found, a new user should be created with a new `id` and `external_ids` containing the event.external_id value.
The system can receive multiple concurrent events for the same `external_id` (which should point to the same user `id`).
The reason `external_ids` is defined as an array and not a simple string is because the there is a different kind of event that can specify an `id` and an `external_id` to add to that user (so future events can resolve the same user `id` using different `external_ids`).

Simple pseudocode demonstrating my desired flow:

```
event = read_event()
external_id = event.external_id;
internal_user = exec_sql(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE external_ids && text["{external_id}"]`)
if not internal_user:
    internal_user = exec_sql(`INSERT INTO users (external_ids) VALUES(text["{external_id}"])`)
write_response(internal_user)
```

This code does not handle a case where 2 concurrent threads get nothing from the SELECT statement. It then INSERTs 2 different rows to the `users` tables for the same value, which should never happen.

I use PostgreSQL 11.
I have read the documentation for [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/transaction-iso.html) and [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html) (and its "ON CONFLICT" section) along with trying to find a suitable answer online, it seems that with an index it is possible to force unique arrays but not unique array values in arrays as described in [Postgres UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443716/postgres-unique-constraint-for-array).

I assume that unnesting the `users` table and moving `external_ids` to a separate `users_external_ids` table which will be defined somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_external_ids (
    id REFERENCES users(id), /* internal unique ID from the users table */
    external_id text, /* single external_id (this table will have multiple rows to represent the array) */
)
```

can allow the use of `INSERT ON CONFLICT (id, external_id) DO NOTHING` for this table.

Finally, my questions are:

- Is there another solution that would not involve changing the current data model? (and at what cost, this is probably the preferable solution for me)
- Am I correct assuming splitting the tables is the "correct" course of action and will solve the problem I face?
- Is there something I'm missing here?

Thank you

Comment: If you are concerned about concurrency, then I think that a separate mapping table would better fit your application needs.

Comment: Using a properly normalized model would make this a lot easier

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you think my suggestion of "users_external_ids" table is the way to do the mapping table you mentioned?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean with a normalized model? my suggestion for the "users_external_ids" would be a normalized model?

Comment: @user9328202 . . . Yes, that would be an appropriate mapping table.

Comment: "The reason external_ids is defined as an array and not a simple string is because the there is a different kind of event that can specify an id and an external_id"  If it is a different kind of event, it should probably have a different kind of column to hold its ids.

Comment: What you want is perhaps an EXCLUDE constraint.  The problem is that GIN indexes don't support EXCLUDE constraints, and GiST indexes lack a supporting operator for text[] type.  But you might be able to build or find such an operator.