# How can I enforce constraints on many-to-many relationships in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

Suppose I have two tables: `thread` and `user`, with a join table `thread_user` that models a many-to-many relationship between them.

Suppose I want to enforce the following constraints:

- A `thread` can have at most 10 `user`s.
- No two `thread`s should have the same set of `user`s.

How can this be done? The first constraint seems easy enough to enforce with a trigger (is there a better approach?). The second constraint I have no idea how to enforce.

Comment: Do the sets of users for two different threads have to have empty intersection, or is it enough that the sets are not the same?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's only required that they are not the same set. The intersections don't have to be empty. These are "threads" as in a chat application, so many threads can have overlapping users, but ideally you won't have two threads that have the same set of users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could imagine a combination of triggers and constraints/indexes.  Actually, you *could* just use triggers, but that requires handling updates, inserts, and deletes.

Instead, you can modify `threads` to have two additional columns:

- The number of users
- An array of the users

You can keep these up-to-date using triggers.  Actually, the first isn't really necessary.

Then you can create a check constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_num_users (num_users <= 10);
```

If you keep the array in sorted order, you can just add a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_users on (users);
```

Or you can define your own `sort_array()` function, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443716/postgres-unique-constraint-for-array).

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Not the trigger I imagined, because I was thinking there must be a way without denormalizing, but this makes sense.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky . . . I would be very careful about the threads not having the same set of users.  That seems like it might have unexpected consequences.