# Create unique character varying array postgres

Tags: postgresql

I had tried to create unique index for `charactery varying[]` column. I create a function modified from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449165/1114443) which type was integer[]. When append a lists of string, the array results in duplicate.

**Code**

```
create function sort_array(character varying[]) returns character varying[] as $$
    select array_agg(n) from (select n from unnest($1) as t(n) order by n) as a;
$$ language sql immutable;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ip_uniq ON table.external (sort_array(ip));
```

**When update**

```
UPDATE table.external SET ip = array_cat(ip,'{1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2}') WHERE id = NO_ID
```

**Result**

> ip = {1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2}

**Expected**

> ip = {1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2}

Comment: The sorted array is only stored in the index, not the table because your UPDATE statement does use the `sort_array` function.